# Как создать адаптивную линию из трех кнопок в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qpushbutton

Имеется такой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLineEdit, QFormLayout 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.image_area = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.general_image = QPixmap('lena-2.png').scaled(                  # Images/settings_image.png
            250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation
        )
        self.image_area.setPixmap(self.general_image)

        self.text_width_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_width_size.setText('Введите ширину массива.')

        self.text_height_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_height_size.setText('Введите высоту массива.')

        self.textbox_for_width = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_for_height = QLineEdit()

        self.create_button = QPushButton("Создать")

    def create_layers(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.image_area)
        layout.addRow(self.text_width_size, self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addRow(self.text_height_size, self.textbox_for_height)
        layout.addRow(self.create_button)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
#?        self.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

А именно метод `create_layers()`:

```
def create_layers(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.image_area)
        layout.addRow(self.text_width_size, self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addRow(self.text_height_size, self.textbox_for_height)
        layout.addRow(self.create_button)
```

Так вот, у меня не получается добавить в ряд более двух форм с помощью `addRow`, но чтобы к тому же они были адаптивными.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> void QFormLayout::addRow(QWidget *widget)
>
> Добавляет указанный виджет в конец этого макета формы. Виджет занимает оба столбца.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLineEdit, QFormLayout 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.image_area = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.general_image = QPixmap('lena-2.png').scaled(                  # Images/settings_image.png
            250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation
        )
        self.image_area.setPixmap(self.general_image)

        self.text_width_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_width_size.setText('Введите ширину массива.')

        self.text_height_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_height_size.setText('Введите высоту массива.')

        self.textbox_for_width = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_for_height = QLineEdit()


        self.create_button = QPushButton("Создать")
        self.button_2 = QPushButton("button_2")                              # +++
        self.button_3 = QPushButton("button_3")                              # +++
        self.widget = QWidget()                                              # +++
        layouiH = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)                                   # +++
        layouiH.addWidget(self.create_button)                                # +++
        layouiH.addWidget(self.button_2)                                     # +++
        layouiH.addWidget(self.button_3)                                     # +++
        


    def create_layers(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.image_area)
        layout.addRow(self.text_width_size, self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addRow(self.text_height_size, self.textbox_for_height)
#        layout.addRow(self.create_button)
        layout.addRow(self.widget)                                           # +++
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
#?        self.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> В Вашем коде с одной стороны, создаются 3 кнопки, но они не адаптивны. То-есть, если написать кучу единичек в названии кнопки, то она "вырастет" в ширине и другие две кнопки сделаются маленькими.

> **minimumWidth** : int
>
> Это свойство содержит минимальную ширину виджета в пикселях.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLineEdit, QFormLayout 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.image_area = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.general_image = QPixmap('lena-2.png').scaled(                  # Images/settings_image.png
            250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation
        )
        self.image_area.setPixmap(self.general_image)
        self.text_width_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_width_size.setText('Введите ширину массива.')
        self.text_height_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_height_size.setText('Введите высоту массива.')
        self.textbox_for_width = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_for_height = QLineEdit()

        self.create_button = QPushButton("Создать")
        self.button_2 = QPushButton("написать кучу единичек 1111")     
        self.button_3 = QPushButton("button_3")    
        self.widget = QWidget()                  
        layouiH = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)         
        layouiH.addWidget(self.create_button, stretch=1)      
        layouiH.addWidget(self.button_2, stretch=1)         
        layouiH.addWidget(self.button_3, stretch=1)         

    def create_layers(self):
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.image_area)
        layout.addRow(self.text_width_size, self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addRow(self.text_height_size, self.textbox_for_height)
        layout.addRow(self.widget)  
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.show()
        w1 = self.formBuilder.create_button.width()
        w2 = self.formBuilder.button_2.width()
        w3 = self.formBuilder.button_3.width()
        w = max(w1, w2, w3)
        self.formBuilder.create_button.setMinimumWidth(w)               
        self.formBuilder.button_2.setMinimumWidth(w)
        self.formBuilder.button_3.setMinimumWidth(w)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @GunTHE что не так?

Comment: добрый вечер! Извините, что так поздно пишу. В Вашем коде с одной стороны, создаются 3 кнопки, но они не адаптивны. То-есть, если написать кучу единичек в названии кнопки, то она "вырастет" в ширине и другие две кнопки сделаются маленькими.

Comment: @GunTHE я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: вау! Спасибо!!!

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, а зачем нужно создание пустого виджета? "self.widget'

Comment: @GunTHE проверьте пожалуйста ваш предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: всё равно не понял, зачем он нужен.. :D

Comment: @GunTHE я потратил время для ответа на ваш предыдущий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227464/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-qlabel-%d0%b8-qpushbutton-%d0%b2-pyqt5 и жду вашего решения по нему. А что касается self.widget - то он не пустой, а содержит три кнопки.

Comment: я еще не дошёл до реализации данной формы, можно, пожалуйста, проверить его позже?

Comment: @GunTHE вы можете делать как считаете нужным. Но если вы задаете вопрос и не реагируете на ответ, это как-то странно. The End.

Comment: я чем-то обидел Вас?